# Does removing a Docker Swarm service remove associated volume data?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

If I run `docker service rm <service>`, will the `<service>'s` volume data be deleted? [Documentation on this command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_rm/) does not specify one way or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried it out. The answer is no, the volume data will not be deleted.

```
> docker service create --name test_container --replicas 1 --mount type=volume,source=test_vol,destination=/mnt busybox top
...
verify: Service converged
> docker service rm test_container
test_container
> docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               test_vol
```